# How can I generate complex events in modelica for when statement?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I tryed to use this code:

```
Real x,y;
Boolean trigger(start = true) 
when x < y and trigger then
   trigger = false;
end when;
```

I want to generate event for "when" only once. But my code doesn't work.
How can I generate complex events in modelica for when statement?

Comment: "But my code doesn't work" is not very helpful -- What do you expect to happen, and what does happen? Also, please post a complete, working, example.

Comment: I get translation error, and I think it's invalid code. Code work when i use: `when x < y then ...`. But then i get many events (x < y), that do nothing. I want set trigger only once and not to receive many events after that. I apologize for my bad english

Comment: Well then, post the exact error, and the exact code you use to obtain the error.

Comment: Also, check the documentation if you find relevant examples, e.g. https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.%27when%27.html or http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/when/

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible use more one condition with logical operator "and" in "when" statement. How i understand it's impossible, but documentation doesn't tell about it. Possible use several condition like `when {condition1, condition2, etc} then`, but it work like with operator "or" (conditions do not exclute each other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dymola you get the following error message:

> The computational causality analysis requires the variables trigger
>   to be solved from the equation: when x < y and trigger then trigger =
>   false; end when;
>   however, the when condition also depends on the unknowns.
>
> You may be able to cut the loop by putting 'pre' around these
>   references in the when condition.

Thus the solution would be:

```
Real x,y;
Boolean trigger(start = true) ;
equation
when x < y and pre(trigger) then
   trigger = false;
end when;
```

As you see this is quite simple (and simulates in Dymola), but I haven't checked it in OpenModelica.

Comment: Very thanks, It's simulates in OM too. It's might be simulates without 'pre()', with 'algorithm': 
`Boolean trigger(start = true, fixed = true);
algorithm
  when time > 5 and trigger then
    trigger := false;
  end when;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you seem to be hitting is the first error message `Internal error BackendDAETransform.analyseStrongComponentBlock failed (Sorry - Support for Discrete Equation Systems is not yet implemented)`. This seems to be https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/1232, and I think it is caused by redefining part of your condition variable within the when statement.

You can work around this with `reinit`. See also the [Bouncing ball example](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/bouncing/) and [the reference](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.Operators.%27reinit()%27.html). It needs to act on a state variable, that's why I put the `der(trigger)` in there.

```
model test_when
  Real trigger(start = 1.0, fixed = true);
equation
  der(trigger) = 0;
  when trigger > 0.5 and time > 5 then
    reinit(trigger, 0);
  end when;
  annotation(
    experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 10, Tolerance = 1e-06, Interval = 0.02));
end test_when;
```

Probably there is a nicer way to achieve this. Anybody else got input on this?

You can check the compilation log (Statistics - events) to confirm that only one event was fired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see what it's works and I will be find problem with my implementstion of it.